# Issue passing an array from PHP to Javascript (Jquery) as shown in common answers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to pass an array from an included php file to a javascript (external too);
They both seems to work because: 1) if I try `echo json_encode($array)` on the main page instead of passing it in the script, the output is correct;
2) if I copy and paste this output to the javascript, the script works correctly and add the elements as options of a Select tag.

But if I try to assign in Javascript

```
  var arrayConduttori = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

Like I've found in similar questions here on stackoverflow the whole script doesn't run, and nothing happens with the click event;

```
var clo; //clone della riga in modifica, se devo annullare operazione

//funzione al clikc per immettere entrega
$(document).on('click', "table td a[id^='entr']",function(){
    //se ci sono altre righe in modifica le faccio ridiventare normali
    $('tr.edita').removeClass('edita').replaceWith(clo);
    // mi identifico la riga su cui devo lavorare
    var riga=$(this).attr('id').substr(4,12);
    var trriga='#tr'+riga;
//mi faccio la copia di backup della riga nella variablie clone
clo=$(trriga).clone();
//mi segno i dati che mi servono immettere automaticamente
var turno=$('#turn'+riga).text();
$(trriga).addClass('edita').html('<td id=form colspan=5><h2>Taxi '+riga.substr(1.11)+'</h2>' +
    'Turno '+turno +
    '<ul>' +
    '<li>Conductor</label><select id=selcond></select></li>' +
    '<li><label>Entrega</label><input type=text></li>'+
    '<li><label>Ahorro</label><input type=text></li>'+
    '<li><label>Gastos</label><input type=text></li>'+
    '</ul></td>');
//aggiungo al campo Select le opzioni conduttori dall'array
  var arrayConduttori = <?php echo json_encode($array);?>;
  $.each(arrayConduttori, function(key, value) {
  $('#selcond').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to echo php variables it has to be in a `.php` file.here in your case you are 
echoing in  a `.js` page

php is run on server side and js is loaded from client side .so by the time you are loading .js file,

php is already executed in the server and output is printed in html page.so when u try

```
<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
```

on client side it ll not work.the best way is to send it from server or create a js variable in main page before loading your external js file like this

```
var arrayConduttori = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

and after this include your script

```
<script src='/your script'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hang on! If the JavaScript file is external, how would it know what $array actually is?

Comment: I thought it worked like php includes, including the whole script to the page sharing all the varibles and functions with the rest

Comment: It wouldn't. As there's no way of a .js file of knowing what actually $array is. What you can do, is wrap the logic in .js file in a function, call that function inside of a <script> tag in your PHP file, passing <?php echo json_encode($array); ?> as the argument.